# Javascript image src on click of image

Tags: javascript, src

I'm trying to create a simple image swapper. So I have 20 images on the page, and 1 large one. I want the user to click one of the smaller images from the 20 and it be output into the place of the big image source.

I've only just started but even so my code doesn't seem to validate as the script fails before it even gets to the `console.log`. Also not sure if I'm using `thisID` correctly.

```
<img id='avatar-output' onclick='selectAvatar(thisID)' src='images/avatars/$number.png' />
<script>
    function selectAvatar(thisID){
        var imageSource = document.getElementById ("avatar-output").src;
        console.log("Avatar source is " imageSource);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @BaconJuice yep jQuery already on the page.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<img id='avatar-output' src='images/avatars/$number.png' />
<img class='avatar-small' src='images/avatars/1.png' />
<img class='avatar-small' src='images/avatars/2.png' />
<img class='avatar-small' src='images/avatars/3.png' />
```

JS:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('avatar-small'),
    target = document.getElementById("avatar-output"),
    handler = function() {   target.src = this.src;    };
for (var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) els[i].onclick = handler;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjD93/)

Or, if all small images are together, better use event delegation:

```
var target = document.getElementById("avatar-output");
document.getElementById("avatar-small-wrapper").onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img')  target.src = e.target.src;
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjD93/1/)

**Notes**

- Better separation of content (html) and behavior (inline JS)
- `<script>` element needs `type="text/javascript"` attribute
- Avoid running JavaScript in global scope to avoid creating global variables, polluting `window`. Run in in a closure: `(function(){ /* code here */ })()`

Comment: Hey, I gave this a go but afraid it's not working. The script is running (I added some console logs) but it is not swapping the image.

Comment: Just looked at the HTML and noticed that you have it round the wrong way. The HTML with $number in are the small ones.

Comment: @Francesca Sorry I had a typo. I have included a demo and a event delegation solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in it, change

```
var imageSource = document.getElementById ("avatar-output").src;
```

to

```
var imageSource = document.getElementById("avatar-output").src;
```

since there is a space where it shouldn't be.

Edit: oh and another one in the

```
console.log("Avatar source is " imageSource);
```

line. Add a `+` between your string and your variable like this:

```
console.log("Avatar source is " + imageSource);
```

Comment: Ah good spot. However, even with that changed it still doesn't work. It now crashes out when I click on the icon and says that `selectAvatar()` isn't defined. It also says that there is an unexpected indentifier after `.src;`

Comment: Sorry, I've overseen the second typo ;-)